# How do I convert a datetime column to nvarchar with the format DD/MM/YYYY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select a datetime column in a table. However, I want the select statement to return the datetime as a nvarchar with the format DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is the convert documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Looking through that, it looks like you want style 103:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), getdate(), 103)
```

Comment: is there any occasion where this is not as simple as putting an "n" in front of varchar?

Answer (score 3):

This should help.  It contains all (or most anyway) the different date formats

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Formatting_Dates

I think you'd be better off handling the string conversion in client if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a date in many formats, in your case :

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), YOUR_DATE_TIME, 103) => 15/09/2016
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), YOUR_DATE_TIME, 3) => 15/09/16
```

Syntax:

```
CONVERT('TheDataTypeYouWant', 'TheDateToConvert', 'TheCodeForFormating' * )
```

The code is an integer, here 3 is the third formatting option (without century), if you want the century just change the code to 103.

See more at: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
select CONVERT (NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(nvarchar(10), datefield, 103)
```

Comment: The format for that is exactly what the OP asked for and is in the language of the DB that was specified. I'm not sure what the down votes are all about.

Answer (score 1):

Look up convert in BOL.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054.aspx) with the 103 option.